# On choosing proper contour to evaluate integration

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem requires to choose some contour to show
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-tz}}{t} dt =\log z$$
for $\Re{z}>0$.

The conclusion is almost self-evident since by simply considering the real case $z>0$, we find from Dominated Convergence Theorem that differentiation and integration can be interchanged thus reaching the conclusion for $z>0$, then since the integration on the left-side of the equation defines a holomorphic function on the right half plane, from Identity theorem we get the conclusion.

The problem is how I can choose a suitable contour to evaluate the integral directly? The contour should make use the single polar at $0$, but it is hard to expect that symmetry circle-like and rectangle-like contour works well since the estimate on the left half plane of the integral has to do with the exponential growth of $e^{\cdot}$, so I am still thinking about if any simple contour can be found. Your comment will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I didn't try but what's wrong with the keyhole contour http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Keyhole_contour.svg&imgrefurl=http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Keyhole_contour.svg&h=283&w=283&sz=6&tbnid=FfRJG-ueH92prM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=90&zoom=1&usg=__qjZwHHvqYeLYBFmKM-5X3FUKDmU=&docid=HjrKpPwQUtV7WM&sa=X&ei=lPoNUrfBHaqs4ASVi4Ag&ved=0CD8Q9QEwAg&dur=1540

Comment: Basically I think it is not easy to handle with the outer circle with exponential growth fraction in the left half plane...

Comment: The integrand is an entire function, the singularity at $0$ is removable.